# Desktop settings for monitors not maintaining on reboot

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, desktop-background

**When rebooting: Folder View Icons switched monitors (previously icons on 1 now on 2, etc) and my wallpaper for 1 moves to 2 leaving 1 with a black wallpaper.**

I have tried clearing .cache .kde .local and even .config in order to resolve this issue. Other settings survive reboot (widgets, panels, etc).

Here are my specs:

```
Intel NUC6i3SYK
4GB of RAM Intel Core i3-6100CPU @ 2.3Ghz
Utilizing the i915 Drivers from Intel

Kubuntu 15.10
with kernel version 4.2.0-36-generic

Using an HDMI cable to an Ultrawide LG with resolution 2560x1440
Secondary monitor utilizing Mini-Display port to HDMI adapter 1920 x 1080
```

The output of Xrandr https://paste.ee/p/zo023

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with XFCE, the system tends to use the leftmost monitor for icons and panel placement.  Setting the monitor you want to use, as primary also tells the system to prefer it.

These should also apply to KDE I guess.

Comment: KDE has the setting to choose a Primary Display.
The issues actually is panel setup as well. 
http://i.imgur.com/FicEBqg.png

I am going to test this theory now but I believe if I were to reboot again it would swap the icons between monitors again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed my situation.

1) Unplugged problematic monitor with Mini DisplayPort to HDMI

2) Deleted .kde configuration folder

3) Rebooted and set wallpapers to colors only

4) Tested a few working reboots to see if settings stayed

5) After confirming monitors were no longer switching after reboot re-entered wallpaper/folder view settings. (10 reboots) So far so good!